# Minimize current draw in a section of a circuit

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, automotive, esp32

I'm making a circuit in my car that gets turned on when the blinker lights are activated.

I've already connected appropriate wiring from the positive wires just before the bulbs, with ground connected to the car battery. That circuit is connected to two Arduino microcontrollers, pulling approximately 12V 1A whene the circuit is closed by the blinker signals.

The blinker signal uses a 5A fuse and I cannot simply use a larger fuse due to the wires used in the circuit.

My proposed solution is this (forgive the tacky drawing):

[image]

The ESP32 will be directly wired to the car battery so that it can stay on until needed, and I will have it in a hibernation mode pulling only 0.15 mA, so that it can't kill the car battery.

The idea is that when the blinker turns on it'll send 12V to a converter which will send 3.3V to a GPIO pin, which wakes up the ESP32, so that it can run just fine. When it loses power to the GPIO pin (AKA the blinker turns back off,) it can go back to hibernation mode.

Now, I'm worried because the lowest current consumption I can find from a 12V - 3.3V buck converter is 800mA, which will still blow the fuse. The GPIO pins only need 40mA each, which is much more like what I need. So, my questions are:

1. If I only have the ESP32 GPIO pin connected to the buck converter, do I have any guarantee that it'll only pull 40mA from the circuit of the bulb?
2. If I can't affirm my first question (which I suspect I can't,) then how could I forcefully drop the current draw from converter manually? I hear about solutions like adding a resistor, but it sounds to me like that will not drop the current draw from the bulb circuit at all, and it'll only drop current going to my buck converter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect there are a number of misunderstandings here, which are making it hard to understand the question. Can you clarify what's powering the ESP32 (i.e. why is 3.3v being put into a GPIO pin and not a supply pin), what its actual current draw is (there's a good chance you're misreading the converter datasheet and it won't *actually* draw 800 mA from 12 V), and if the ESP32 is powered somewhere else, why not just use a voltage divider to drive a (tiny) current into the GPIO?

Comment: @Joshuamatheson:  That a converter can supply upto 800 milliamperes doesn't mean it draws all of that all the time.  If your load only draws 100 mA, then the converter will only consume something around 100mA.  Since you are dropping 12V to 3.3V, it will only draw about 30 mA to power a 100 mA load.

Comment: Yeah if you just want the ESP32 to know the blinker is blinking, just use a voltage divider. But since you will be powering the ESP32 from the battery, you need a dc-dc buck converter with low standby current. Please don't use any of these fake LM2596 from ebay.